# Beamer: top align of columns with itemize and image?

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, lists, columns

I have the following MWE and I want to top align the two columns, I do this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T]{.475\textwidth}
        \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=2.25em]
            \itemsep 1.25em
            \item first item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla and more and more text here
            \item second item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla
            \item third item bla bla bla bla some more text bla
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}%
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}[T]{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{example-image}
    \end{column}%
\end{columns}

\bigskip
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]
    \item And yet another item here with some long long long long long long text and some more text bla bla bla
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Which gets me this:

[image: fig]

I do not see the top alignment happening at all... what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Nothing wrong, `itemize` introduces some vertical space before the first line. Replace `itemize` or the image with a regular text and you'll see how the vertical alignment is correct.

Comment: oooohhh I figured... is there a way to remove that vertical space?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. By the way, if you use `beamer's` columns, you don't need `multicol` package. And `enumitem` is not always compatible with `beamer`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- as you have already been told in comments: there is no need to use `multicols` with beamer -- it has its own `column` environment.
- `enumitem` does not play well with `beamer`. As far as I can see, you are only using it to control the left margin of the items, which can easily be adjusted with `\leftmargini`

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}[T, onlytextwidth]{.45\textwidth}%
                \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%
        \begin{itemize}
        \itemsep 1.5em
            \item First item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla and more and more text here
            \item second item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla
            \item third item bla bla bla bla some more text bla
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}[T]{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5cm]{example-image}
    \end{column}%
\end{columns}
\begin{itemize}
    \item And yet another item here with some long long long long long long text and some more text bla bla bla
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Alright makes sense. Can the left margin be changed globally without enumitem?

Comment: @DaniCee Yes, see the code in my answer `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}`

Comment: Ah ok, that would work in the preamble too? I was placing it before each itemize instance...

Comment: Just one quick question: Where can I look at the different column alignments? there is "b" and "T", but "B" throws error and "t" messes everything up... what are them and what other ones do we have? Is there a "C" or "c" for center?

Comment: @DaniCee look into the beamer user guide for the alignments

Comment: I still find trouble centering the two columns... I am going to open a new question

Answer (score 2):

As *Ignasi* pointed out in his comment above, `enumitem` is not always compatible with beamer. See, if the following rude solution without  `enumitem` is acceptable to you:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\hrule\bigskip% only for test purpose, delete in real document

\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}[T]{.48\textwidth}\vspace*{-1ex}
        \begin{itemize}
            \itemsep 1.25em
            \item first item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla and more and more text here
            \item second item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla
            \item third item bla bla bla bla some more text bla
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}[T]{.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=5cm]{example-image}
    \end{column}%
\end{columns}

\bigskip
\begin{itemize}
    \item And yet another item here with some long long long long long long text and some more text bla bla bla
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]