# Beamer center vertical alignment of two columns

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment, two-column, columns

Given the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}
\begin{columns}[c, onlytextwidth]%EVEN SPECIFYING THE c OPTION
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%AND EVEN REMOVING EXTRA itemize SPACE
        \begin{itemize}
        \itemsep 1.5em
            \item First item bla bla bla bla some more text
            \item second item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla
            \item third item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla bla bla bla bla
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5.5cm]{example-image}
    \end{column}%
\end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Is it me or the two columns do not align properly? It seems there are more space left on the top of the image (noted in red) than on the bottom (in black)... Note as well that I added the following line, as indicated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351315/beamer-top-align-of-columns-with-itemize-and-image)...

> \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%

[image: fig]

Any idea?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1858/stable-vertical-alignment-of-columns-in-beamer).

Comment: My question would then be: Why doesn't "\begin{columns}[c]" work like it is supposed to?

Comment: Related?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148365/how-do-i-ask-beamer-to-exactly-fill-up-a-slide

Comment: It is `itemize`'s fault. Replace `itemize` by a normal paragraph and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems `itemize` inserts some spacing above the environment, just as `center` does. A fix for the example you've provided is to put the figure in a `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some title}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0.5em}
\begin{columns}[c, onlytextwidth]%EVEN SPECIFYING THE c OPTION
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}%
        \setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}%AND EVEN REMOVING EXTRA itemize SPACE
        \begin{itemize}
        \itemsep 1.5em
            \item First item bla bla bla bla some more text
            \item second item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla
            \item third item bla bla bla bla some more text bla bla bla bla bla bla
        \end{itemize}
    \end{column}%
    \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=5.5cm]{example-image}
    \end{center}
    \end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was already embedding the images in "figure" environments to try, so I will give the bounty to your answer cause conceptually makes more sense to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Here is the workflow:

1. Insert `\hrule` at the places you want to investigate.

[image]

2. Extra spaces gone! Great! Now replace `\hrule` by `\hrule height0pt`.

[image]

3. Problem solved.

## Explanation

`\hrule` is one of the simplest objects in TeX and it does not produce extra spaces. By inserting `\hrule`, it is easier to **see** the spaces. (For example, setting `\partopsep` to zero seems to make no change. But with `\hrule`s you will see the difference.)

Sometimes `\hrule` absorbs unwanted spaces. In this case, just keep those `\hrule`s and turn your attention to something more important.